# SQL Unique Rows from single table

Tags: sql, informix

Here is my table:

```
family  symbol
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   D
2   F
2   E
```

The result I want is 2 rows:  1,A,B,C and 2,D,E,F.  The order doesn't matter.

This:

```
SELECT T.family, T.symbol,T1.Symbol, T2.symbol
From T
    inner join T as T1 on T.family = T1.family
    inner join T as T2 on T.family = T2.family
WHERE T.symbol <> T1.symbol
    AND T.symbol <> T2.symbol
    AND T1.symbol <> T2.symbol
```

Gives this:

```
family  symbol  Symbol  symbol
1   A   C   B
1   A   B   C
1   B   C   A
1   B   A   C
1   C   B   A
1   C   A   B
2   D   E   F
2   D   F   E
2   F   E   D
2   F   D   E
2   E   F   D
2   E   D   F
```

The actual table has multiple family values, each with a variable number of symbols.

Comment: This is already and existing duplicate.Take a look over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584307/tsql-query-pivoting

Comment: I am working in Informix, so I don't have group_concat or pivoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a complete implementation of GROUP_CONCAT for Informix in [Show a one to many relationship as 2 columns - 1 unique row (ID & comma separated list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate/716655#716655).  It will certainly handle the data you show.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the solution I was looking for.  I can't vote up because I don't have the requisite reputation, but I would if I could.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a pivot table.  Take a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

See if you can apply your logic to a pivot and that should give you the results you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select family, group_concat(symbol separator ',')
  from T
 group by family
```

It's not **exactly** what you want, but maybe it's close enough. It will concatenate all different symbols for each family into **a single column**. Query is simple and you don't need to use OLAP or any other complex SQL construction.